# socket.io messages not appearing

Tags: express, socket.io

I am trying to learn to use Socket.io with Express. No error messages appeared but strangely it's not working. The servermessage is not appearing and clicking the send button doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),
function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.
get('port'));
});

require('./routes/sockets.js').initialize(server);

module.exports = app;
```

routes/sockets.js

```
var io = require('socket.io');
exports.initialize = function(server) {
io = io.listen(server);
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
socket.send(JSON.stringify(
{type:'serverMessage',
message: 'Welcome to the most interesting chat room on earth!'}));
socket.on('message', function(message){
message= JSON.parse(message);
if(message.type == "userMessage"){
socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
message.type = "myMessage";
socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
});
});
};
```

public/javascripts/chat.js

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#messages').append('<div class="'+data.type+'">' + data.message +
'</div>');
});
$(function(){
$('#send').click(function(){
var data = {
message: $('#message').val(),
type:'userMessage'
};
socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
$('#message').val('');
});
});
```

views/index.jade

```
extends layout

block append head

script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/chat.js')


block content
  section#chatroom
    div#messages
    input#message(type='text', placeholder='Enter your message here')
    input#send(type='button', value='Send')
```

views/layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  block head
    title= title

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
      header#banner
        h1 Awesome Chat

      block content
      footer Hope you enjoy your stay here

      script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js')
```

Comment: I suggest you should have `socket.on('connect')` in client side to check if socket is open or not first.

Comment: There's no need to manually `JSON.stringify()` before sending.  socket.io will do that automatically if you pass an object.

Comment: Please indent your scripts appropriately in your question so they are readable.

Comment: How do you do that, I am pure beginner in programming.

Comment: Hi Phatthana, I did that with socket.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});   and nothing comes up which means there's no connection. Any idea why?